# Laravel handle error that only thrown by controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I am creating a logic where a controller can call another controller depend on Auth::user() role, but not all of controller shared same method, so i want if controller calling a method that does not exist it will throw a 404 not found. 
here is my controller

```
class LokalController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    Public $controller;
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('adminakses');
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->setController();
            return $next($request);
        });
    }
    public function setController()
    {
        $role = Auth::user()->role;
        switch ($role)
        {
            case 'admin':
                $this->controller = new \SIA\Http\Controllers\Admin\LokalController;
                break;
            case 'guru':
                $this->controller = new \SIA\Http\Controllers\Guru\LokalController;
                break;
            case 'siswa':
                $this->controller = new \SIA\Http\Controllers\Guru\LokalController;
                break;

        }
    }
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->controller->index();
    }
```

for example Admin\LokalController has method A(), but Guru\LokalController doesn't, and if user logged in as guru and trying to cal method A() it should returning not found exception or something user understandable message, but currently showing BadMethodCallException method A() does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you're trying to work is achievable but I think it will be overwhelming in time.

```
public function index()
{
    try { 
       $action = $this->controller . '@' . __FUNCTION__;
       action($action);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        abort('401', "Your Message");
    }
}
```

---

How I'd do it instead is, I'd create a redirect path for the User model.

```
public function getRedirectPathAttribute() {
    switch ($this->role) {
        case 'admin':
            return '/admin';
        case 'guru':
            return '/guru';
        case 'siswa':
            return '/siswa';
    }
}
```

And then create a middleware to make the check, and if redirect is needed, I'd redirect using `auth()->user()->redirect_path`.

What do you think?

Comment: Since i do not want to change the route, and different role can acces sam url, i think it will be better if we handle everyting inside the controller without being redirected.

Comment: By the way your solution is still returning BadMethodCallException

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have a controller all this controllers inherits from that implement all methods by calling App::abort(404), and in each of the child classes implement the methods they need, stopping the methods in the parent classes from being called

```
class BaseController extends Controller{
  public function a() {
    App::abort(404);
  }
}

class AdminController extends BaseController{
  public function a() {
    // to stuff for admin
  }
}
```

Controllers inheriting from BaseController that don't implement a() will get 404, admin controller will not